# Convert bigint to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, teamcity

I want to convert a value from bigint to datetime.

For example, I'm reading the ***HISTORY*** table of ***teamcity server***. On the field ***build_start_time_server***, I have this value on one record 1283174502729.

How can I convert it to a datetime value?

Comment: I changed the tags to hopefully make them more specific.  Note that if you use "sql server" in the tag field this will go under the *sql* tag as well as the *server* tag but not under the *sql-server* tag which is probably what you want.

Comment: What datetime value do you want for 1283174502729?

Comment: Agreed with @krock. Since your question isn't specific to what implementation of SQL you want (example: sql-server), there are a lot of answers here which are not applicable depending on the flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Does this work for you? It returns 30-8-2010 13:21:42 at the moment on SQL Server 2005:

```
select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 1283174502729) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

I've divided by 1000 because the dateadd function won't work with a number that large. So you do lose a little precision, but it is much simpler to use.

Comment: The second param is INT, no BIGINT. That is, remove CONVERT. Is not neccesary

Answer (score 7):

Slightly different approach:

Your scenario:

```
SELECT dateadd(ms, 1283174502729 / 86400000, (1283174502729 / 86400000) + 25567)
FROM yourtable
```

Generic code:

```
SELECT dateadd(ms, yourfield / 86400000, (yourfield / 86400000) + 25567)
FROM yourtable
```

Output:

```
August, 30 2010 00:00:14
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9eb5a/2/0

Answer (score 4):

```
CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(CAST(dateadd(s, convert(bigint, [t_stamp]) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00')) AS DATETIMEOFFSET), DATENAME (TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I still don't understand the vote down. Are there errors? This works for 2008R2. Is it inefficient?  How can I improve if I don't know what to improve.

Comment: I would imagine the downvote was for providing a code only answer without any explanation as to what it is doing or why it works.

Answer (score 2):

To convert bigint to datetime/unixtime, you must divide these values by 1000000 (10e6) before casting to a timestamp.

```
SELECT
     CAST( bigIntTime_column / 1000000 AS timestamp) example_date
FROM example_table
```

Simple and easy solution which won't require any added library or function to be imported

Comment: This solution is easier and it worked better for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following takes new SQL terminology into account and will return the milliseconds (can also be modified for use in a calculated field.) [SQL Server 2012 or later]

```
declare @StartDate datetime2(3) = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
, @milliseconds bigint = 1283174502729
, @MillisecondsPerDay int = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 -- = 86400000

SELECT  DATEADD(MILLISECOND, TRY_CAST(@milliseconds % @millisecondsPerDay AS 
INT), DATEADD(DAY, TRY_CAST(@milliseconds / @millisecondsPerDay AS INT), 
@StartDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

select Cast(Cast(19980324 as nvarchar) as Datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If you want precision in milliseconds to be maintained then you could do as follows. Works on SQL server 2016

```
SELECT dateadd(ms, ((CONVERT(bigint, build_start_time_server)%1000)), 
       dateadd(ss, ((CONVERT(bigint, build_start_time_server)/1000)%60), 
       dateadd(mi, ((CONVERT(bigint, build_start_time_server)/1000)/60), '1970-01-01'))) FROM yourtable
```

The answer I got was

```
Monday, August 30, 2010 1:21 PM
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DATEADD(second,YourValue, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime))
```

Comment: Downvoted. "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int." with the data provided in the question.

Comment: Nevertheless with a bit of tweaks it could work, perhaps the poster can work it out a bit ? (upvoted to encourage him a bit :) )

Answer (score -3):

Did you try `FROM_UNIXTIME`?

```
select from_unixtime('your_field') from 'your_table'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Works for me.