# Stream Analytics - How would I convert timestamp in string to Date/Time?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

So I have timestamp which I need to convert into time. So I have tried this

[Convert From Bigint to datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-from-bigint-to-datetime-value)

But it is not working in Azure Function App :/

Basically I have this code

```
SELECT
dateadd(s, convert(bigint, XEvent.[Timestamp]) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
FROM
    TwoPartitionXEventHub
```

**Edit 1**

I get following error:
Expression is not supported: 'convert ( bigint , XEvent . [Timestamp] )'.

**Edit 2**

I have tried like this too:

```
dateadd(s, SQL_BATCH_COMPLETED.[Timestamp]/1000,'1-1-1970 00:00:00')
```

But it returns unknown error

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn834997.aspx)

Comment: The query you provided looks OK. Please provide sample data and error message that you are getting

Comment: I get error when calling convert function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was using timestamp that was ULONGLONG which is bigger than bigint. After converting that timestamp locally into SYSTEMTIME insted of FILETIME i did not need to convert anything in Azure it was already in datetime format.

Thanks!