# Select rows between two date that bigint with adddate

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

I have a table in MSSQL Server that save date as bigInt type like `1503381651490`. Now I want to select rows that `created_time` between `2017-01-01` to `2017-03-28`. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Start from here [Convert From Bigint to datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-from-bigint-to-datetime-value)

Comment: Use proper column data types...

Comment: @jarlh this DB is not for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert From Bigint to datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-from-bigint-to-datetime-value)

Comment: is the bigint value the UNIX timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with this:

```
SELECT  "chdt"."CHANGEID" AS "Change ID",     "chdt"."CREATEDTIME" AS "Created 
Date", "chdt"."TITLE" AS "Title" FROM "ChangeDetails" "chdt"
WHERE  dateadd(s,("chdt"."CREATEDTIME" / 1000),'1970/01/01') >= '2017/10/01' 
AND (dateadd(s,("chdt"."CREATEDTIME" / 1000),'1970/01/01') <= '2017/10/05')
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to convert the `bigint` fields to `Date` in order to apply the filters. You can use the below conversion for that.

```
10000000 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 864000000000

SELECT CAST((bigintvalue - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS DATETIME) AS DateTimeConv;
```

After that you can apply the filters on the converted date field.
For example

```
SELECT CAST((created_time - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS DATETIME) AS DateTimeConv
FROM Table1
WHERE DateTimeConv < MaxDateValue
      AND DateTimeConv > MinDateValue;
```

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you should store the datetime in its correct format.

For now, assuming the value stored is UNIX timestamp, you can convert the required date range to unix timestamp:

```
select *
from your_table
where created_time between datediff(minute,'1990-1-1','2017-01-01')
                       and datediff(minute,'1990-1-1','2017-03-28')
```