# Convert SQL BigInt as 1811011439 to date time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Datetime row is look something like this format

```
1811011439
1811011439
1811011439
1811011439
1811011439
1811011439
```

It can read like this

```
Y. 18
M. 11
D. 01
```

at the first line as you see

Could any please guide me how can I convert it to date readable format.

Comment: That sure looks like a very strange "datetime" value - what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert From Bigint to datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-from-bigint-to-datetime-value)

Comment: The `BIGINT` number here represent what? milliseconds? seconds? what's the logic here? Also what did you try to solve it?

Comment: The correct thing to do is to change how that data is stored - if it's a datetime value it should be stored as a DateTime2, not as anything else.

Comment: Oh great - 2 digit years. Have we learned NOTHING from Y2K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to convert a string represantation of the datetime value (stored as bigint) to a readable format. In this case you can `CAST` the date part of the string / bigint to a `DATE` value:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CAST(1811011439 AS VARCHAR), 6) AS DATE)
-- 2018-11-01
```

I recommend to use a `DATETIME` column instead of a `BIGINT` column to store values likes this. With the following `SELECT` you get all the `DATETIME` values:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(1811011439 AS VARCHAR), 1, 6) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CAST(1811011439 AS VARCHAR), 7, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(1811011439 AS VARCHAR), 9, 2) AS DATETIME)
-- 2018-11-01 14:39:00.000
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the request, your date in VARCHAR format as 'YYMMDDHHmm', so, the easiest way is:

```
DECLARE @TextDate AS NVARCHAR(20) = '1811011439';
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@TextDate, 1, 6) AS DATE);
```

Or if that's in a field in one table:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(YourField, 1, 6) AS DATE) FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your column isn't a `BIGINT` datatype, it's `VARCHAR` and you want to split the date from it

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('1811011439', 6) AS DATE)
```

If it's really a `BIGINT` column, just convert it to `VARCHAR`, split it and then `CAST` as `DATE`

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CAST(YourColumn AS VARCHAR), 6) AS DATE)
SELECT CAST(LEFT(YourColumn, 6) AS DATE) --It works too
```

Still, the correct answer to this is to use the right datatype which is `DATETIME`