# Entity Framework bigint to datetime migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a model that currently stores the time in seconds since the epoch as an `Int64`. Requirements have changed and now I need to store the date as a `DateTime`. I'm still fairly new to Entity Framework. I tried changing the type in the model and making a new migration and the database complains that it doesn't know how to convert a `BigInt` to a `DateTime`. Is there a way to specify a conversion for `BigInt` to `DateTime` when I run a migration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-from-bigint-to-datetime-value

Comment: right, but when running a migration script from entity framework

Comment: Try making the change to the model and generating the migration, then edit the migration to run that script instead of whatever was generated.

Comment: This would be a custom step, since there is no simple, uniform way of converting between these values. You could create a custom `MigrationOperation` class for it, though that might be overkill for a one-off operation.

Comment: If possible, simply add the calculated column either in your table/view or entity framework. If not, then on the database - create a new column of the type DateTime, set the value: update tbl set NewDateColumn = dateadd(S, [unixtime], '1970-01-01') then rename BigInt column adding suffix _OLD (or delete it) and finally rename newly created DateTime column. Of course, you will need to refresh the entity framework after this.