# SQL: Convert bigint type to formatted date

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

I believe this is a simple question, but I've been searched around and got no satisfactory answer.

Basically I have a `Bigint` object in MYSQL, I want to convert it to date format like `20201004`, for example:

```
1601625689496 -> (20201002)
```

I've tried

```
to_date(cast(1601625689496 as timestamp))
date(cast(1601625689496 as timestamp))
```

But neither allow formatting, I hope to get the easiest and fastest conversion.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?. Date funtions are highly database-specific.

Comment: The real question is: why isn't that column defined as a `timestamp`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bigint to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-bigint-to-datetime)

Comment: hi, I have modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your number is an epoch timestamp in milliseconds (that is, the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970), you can use `from_unixtime()`:

```
select from_unixtime(1601625689496 / 1000)
```

This gives you a `datetime` value. If you want to drop the time component, then:

```
select date(from_unixtime(1601625689496 / 1000))
```

Note that `1601625689496` actually maps to `2020-10-02`, not `2020-10-04`.

Comment: hi, I've tried `date`, I'd like to format it to `yyyyMMdd`, without the dash `-`

Comment: @MJeremy: so you want a string, not a date: `date_format(from_unixtime(1601625689496 / 1000), '%Y%m%d')`.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the best I got so far, this one works for me `date_format(from_unixtime(1601625689), 'YYYYMMdd')`