# Converting bigint to datetime in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, bigint

I am trying to convert my bigint into a date and time. I have used the following link as a guidedance but it is not working as it is suppose to because from my understanding in this solution it is based on a millesecond.

[Convert bigint to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-bigint-to-datetime)

I have the following coding and have tried the following:

```
declare @starttime as bigint;
set @starttime = '2021021209295600000';

Select dateadd(HOUR, (@starttime / 100000) % (24 * 60 * 60),
               dateadd(day, (@starttime / 100000) / (24 * 60 * 60), '1970-01-01'))
```

The following error is being prompted:

```
The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the add operator.
```

Also as mentioned earlier I have tried the above mentioned solution however the following output is given which is incorrect `select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, @starttime) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))`

Can someone help me please? The **expected value** is `2021-02-12 09:29:56`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but I would `CONVERT` it to a `varchar`, inject some of the needed characters, and then `CONVERT` to a `datetime` (as you have 5 decimal places, I assume it's actually meant to be a `datetime2(5)`):

```sql
DECLARE @starttime as bigint;
SET @starttime = 2021021209295600000;

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(5),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(20),@starttime),15,0,'.'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,'T'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-'));
```

Comment: thanks. I have even tried something similar but an error was prompted `select convert(datetime, cast(@starttime/100000 as varchar(14)), 101)` , however yours work

Comment: Because `'20210212092956'` isn't a valid value either, @AnnaliseAzzopardi , it doesn't have any of the separators (such as `-` and `:`). That's what all those `STUFF` functions are doing; injecting the characters into the right place.

Comment: and would it be possible to just select the date only instead of date and time. I have tried the following but an error is given: `,CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(char(8),@starttime),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')) as DateOnly`

Comment: Use a `date`, @AnnaliseAzzopardi .