# How to convert string to datetime in sql-server

Tags: sql-server

I have string 20201001163318811 and I want to convert this into below format

2020-10-01 16:33:18.811

i.e

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting bigint to datetime in sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66169760/2029983)

Comment: Dates have no formats, they're binary values. Almost all databases have date types. Dates should *never* be stored as strings or numbers

Comment: @Larnu that's the one i was looking for.. thanks a lot